# Why Python "global" statement is always evaluated, even under conditional statement that is not met?

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, global-variables, global

I don't know how to explain the case, just try for yourself:

```
x = 7
def f():
    if False:
        global x
        print("global")
    x += 1

f()
print(x)
```

In my opinion, the above code should result in "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment", but instead it not only works, but it changes the global variable 'x'.

Comment: But `x` is defined . . . right above the function.

Comment: @It_is_Chris Without `global x`, we would get an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`

Comment: `global` is a declaration more than a statement.  The interpreter gathers them up when "pre-compiling", not at execution time.

Comment: See [the documentation for global](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) for details.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, well, I don't see there anything about it being evaluated in the block of code that is not supposed to be evaluated at all. If it is intended behaviour, then it's the deepest pitfall in Python I've ever seen... Isn't Python supposed to be a script language, evaluated at the time of execution?

Comment: Oh, that's not the deepest pitfall by any means.  I've been using Python for 25 years, and this is the first time I've seen this come up.  Overgeneralizing, the use of `global` generally indicates a design flaw anyway.

Comment: " global is a directive to the parser." - so it's not some instruction that gets run when you execute the code. "The global statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block" - so it doesn't matter if you put it at the beginning or anywhere in the body of the function.

Answer (score 1):

A function gets a local namespace every time it is called. Python needs a way to know which variables are defined in that namespace or a containing namespace. Instead of requiring that all local variables be declared local, python's rule is that any variable that is assigned in a function is local to that function. It figures this out at compile time.

The `global` keyword does the opposite. It tells python that in this single function, assignment to the "global" variable is really an assignment in the enclosing namespace. Like local variables, this is figured out when the function is compiled. Because of compilation issues, python requires that the `global` be declared before the first reference to the variable. This is a compile thing, not a runtime thing, so its okay for it to be in a block that isn't ever really run.